# SSDT2012 version SSIS package can be execute on SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, sql-job

I have upgraded my VS2005 - SSIS project to VS 2013 (SSDT2012). And I am using SQL Server 2012. Where I need to execute SSIS package using `Integration Service Catalog` for SQL Server job. But I get some error and I got to know that SSDT-2012 version can not be execute in SQL Server 2012.

I don't have any chance to downgrade SSIS package version. So is there any other way to execute a SSDT-2012 SSIS package in a SQL Server 2012 job?

Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Can you post your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build SQL Server 2012 ssis packages you need to install SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 or SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012. SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 is used to build ssis packages for SQL Server 2014 only.

**References**

- [Installing Integration Services Versions Side by Side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/installing-integration-services-versions-side-by-side?view=sql-server-2017)
- [SSIS tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssis/info)

Comment: Thanks lot for this info. but i will have to move the project into VS2015 now, bad for me! thanks bdwy